# Unix: copy a file with original permission in C

Tags: c, linux, unix

I am trying to make a copy program. It's similar to cp function in linux. I can copy a file successfully using ./copy file1 file2, but somehow the premission from the source is not copied to the destination. Does anyone know how to do this? Example and code are shown below :)

My files and their original permission.
[image: My files and their original permission.]

Successfully copied the file but the permission was not copied.
[image: Successfully copied the file but the permission was not copied.]

```
#define buff_s      4096
#define mod        0644

void printError(char *, char *);

main(int ac, char *txts[])
{
    int     input, output, n_chars;
    char    buf[buff_s];

    struct stat file1;
    struct stat file2;
    stat(txts[1], &file1);
    stat(txts[2], &file2);

    if ( (input=open(txts[1], O_RDONLY)) == -1 )
        printError("error", av[1]);

    if ( (output=creat( txts[2], mod)) == -1 )
        printError( "error", txts[2]);
```

Comment: Note also that `read()` and `write()` return `ssize_t` instead of `int`.  They are *not* the same.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: Garg365, I will try the method you provide, I think it will work as well

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need to read the permissions of the source file and set the same permissions on the destination file.  You can use `stat()` to read the permissions and `chmod()` to set them:

```
#include <sys/stat.h>

void copyPermission(const char* fromFile, const char* toFile) {
    struct stat tmp;
    stat(fromFile, &tmp);
    chmod(toFile, tmp.st_mode);
}
```

(N.B. error-checking omitted).

In your `main` function at the bottom you can just simply do this:

```
chmod(av[2], file1.st_mode);
```

The other option is to simply create the file with the right permissions:

Instead of:

```
if ( (out_fd=creat( av[2], COPYMODE)) == -1 )
```

do

```
if ( (out_fd=creat( av[2], file1.st_mode)) == -1 )
```

Comment: Since the file is being copied and there are open file descriptors to the process, you can also use `fstat()` and `fchmod()` on the file descriptors directly.

Comment: I believe the second solution you gave me is the best one. Thank you for helping me :). lesson learned, i never thought it was that simple.

Comment: Andrew Henle, I will try your method and update the solution shortly. (If it works)